# 'Target not mounted' on React Joyride

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to run React Joyride on a page with a modal. The modal opens on stepIndex 3, and step 4 should be inside the modal, but instead I get a warning `Target not mounted`, and it skips to step 5.

I've tried to add a `setTimeout` inside the callback, but it does not work.

```
  const handleJoyrideCallback = (data: any) => {
    const { action, index, status, type } = data;
    const nextStepIndex = index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1);

    if ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND].includes(type)) {
      setState({ run: false, loading: true });
      setTimeout(() => {
        setState({
          loading: false,
          run: true,
          stepIndex: index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1),
        });
      }, 2000);


    } else if ([STATUS.FINISHED, STATUS.SKIPPED].includes(status)) {
      setState({ run: false });
      setJoyride(false);

    } else if (type === EVENTS.TOOLTIP_CLOSE) {
      setState({ stepIndex: index + 1 });
    }

    if ([ACTIONS.NEXT] && index === 3) {
      openModal(true);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect`. It'll watch for the modal to open, and then show the step inside that modal.

1. Add `modalOpen` to the state to track if the modal is open or not.
2. Use `useEffect` to watch for changes in `modalOpen`.
3. When the modal opens, update the step index to show the step inside the modal.
4. Update the callback function to open the modal and set `modalOpen` when you reach the right step (stepIndex 3).

Now `Joyride` should only show the step inside the modal when the modal is open, fixing the warning and showing the step as expected.

Here's the breakdown:

First, add a `modalOpen` property to your state:

```
    const [state, setState] = useState({
    run: false,
    loading: false,
    stepIndex: 0,
    modal open: false,
    });
```

Add `useEffect` to wait for the `modalOpen`:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (state.modalOpen) {
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          run: true,
          stepIndex: 4,
        }));
      }
    }, [state.modalOpen]);
```

Finally update the `handleJoyrideCallback` function so that it sets modalOpen when it reaches `stepIndex` = 3:

```
    const handleJoyrideCallback = (data) => {
    const { action, index, status, type } = data;

  if ([EVENTS.STEP_AFTER, EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND].includes(type)) {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      run: false,
      loading: true,
    }));

    setTimeout(() => {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        loading: false,
        run: true,
        stepIndex: index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1),
      }));
    }, 2000);
  } else if ([STATUS.FINISHED, STATUS.SKIPPED].includes(status)) {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, run: false }));
    setJoyride(false);
  } else if (type === EVENTS.TOOLTIP_CLOSE) {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, stepIndex: index + 1 }));
  }

  if (action === ACTIONS.NEXT && index === 3) {
    openModal(true);
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, modalOpen: true }));
  }
};
```

Comment: The problem was actually that I hadn't set the joyride to controlled.. I had to add 
`stepIndex={state.stepIndex}`
to the Joyride-function to set the controlled-boolean to true, then it all worked. Thank you for your help!